# Arduino struct variable seems to be reassigned without explicit reassignment

Tags: c++, variables, struct, arduino

Using the Arduino IDE I am trying to use a struct for an object that controls buttons.

I assign a value of 14 for the `fillAndFire.pin` value.

```
fillAndFire.pin    = 14;
```

Later, the code reassigns the value to zero, but it should not.

```
displayLine[i] = displayLine[i-1];
```

Full code:

```
char* displayLine[15];

struct Buttons{
  int pin;
  int lightPin;
  bool io;
  bool pressed;
  uint8_t* bName;
} fillAndFire;

void setup() {

  //start Serial service
  Serial.begin(9600);
  while (!Serial){
    delay(1);
  }

  //define pin
  fillAndFire.pin    = 14;

  //message 1 gives a value of 14
  Serial.print("fillAndFire.pin 1 = ");Serial.println(fillAndFire.pin);

  //mysteriously, this changes the value of Buttons fillAndFire.pin from 14 to 0
  //if I change the 15 to 14, it does not affect the fillAndFire.pin variable. 
  //other numbers, like "1" works just fine, but not 2, 3 or 14
  //even other assignments, like "fillAndFire.lightpin = 14" works?!?!?!
   displayLine[15] = displayLine[13];

  //message 4 gives a value of 0, 
  //but it has not be explicitly reassigned
  Serial.print("fillAndFire.pin 4 = ");Serial.println(fillAndFire.pin);
}

void loop() {
}
```

Comment: It seems like this question should stand. The specific lack of error handling is uncommon in modern programming languages and simply understanding that errors are handled poorly by microcontrollers may help people troubleshoot their code, as it did mine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know if the following influences, but it seems you have a 15 length `char*` vector, that is `displayLine[0..14]`, and in the for loop of the assignment, in the first iteration it will happen a `displayLine[15]` that does not exists. In a computer it should result in a Segmentation Fault, but in Arduino may be the reason. Try `for(int i = 14; ...)`

Comment: spot on. That mistake was wreaking havoc. Everything is running smoothly now.

Comment: Yes, as the ATMega328 doesn't have an MMU pretty much any invalid memory access will silently corrupt unrelated memory. By the way, even on "regular" PCs often you are not going to get any segfault - you have to trespass into a non mapped memory page for that, or to seriously corrupt data structures that will in turn lead to crashes (e.g. heap data structures).